# "On it" or "by it" when referring to travelling by subway?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which one I have to use: *on it* or *by it* when referring to travelling by subway? For example:

> The Kyiv subway is very convenient. You can get practically everywhere **on it**/**by it**.

Are both perfectly natural?

Comment: I would use _on it_.

Comment: Native speakers don't normally *travel **by** subway* (or ***by tube*** in London, or ***by Metro*** if we're Brits abroad in Paris), even though we use that format for very similar "modes of transport" such as *travel by **road, rail, sea, air, car, bus, train, ship, plane,...*** Probably just because *most* native speakers don't live in those metropolitan areas, so they don't often use or refer to those transport modes (and there's something *slightly* odd about casually conflating "vehicle" and "medium or pathway traveled **through**"). So they travel ***on the** subway / tube / Metro*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the subway, you're usually going to be traveling "on it". So, it's more likely that you would use "on it". "By it" doesn't really fit this situation as it doesn't have the same strength of "on it".